# VSCode pylint failing to lint inserted modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have few custom modules that i am using across other python scripts, like for eg. my own DB manager. Currently in order to use an existing module, I am inserting path inside my python, which works great but it does fail for pylint.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/myuser/Develop/Pipeline/dbconnector")
import dbmanager
```

> Unable to import dbmanager pylint(import-error) [2, 1]

Code works just fine but pylint itself fails. Is it a problem with pylint or is there a more 'correct' way when dealing with custom modules ?

ps. I am still developing those modules to ideally I would love to keep them 'live' as they are so i could quickly tweak on demand

Comment: A typical way of using custom modules is to use a virtual environment and install then as a packages which requires a `setup,py`. The poor man's version of that would be to symlink them into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Pylint doesn't execute your code to analyze it, so it can't pick up the fact that you manipulated `sys.path` that way. You can set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable so that the Python interpreter executing Pylint knows where to look.